# how to know the tag url from stash

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am new to stash and I had always used svn .

I have created a tag (MyApp_4_0) from trunk, in stash after the bug fixes.
I would like to know the tag url for sending the QA release notes. Please let me know the steps to get the tag url.

[image]

Comment: Note that the `git-stash` tag is for the [`git stash` command](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) while [Atlassian Stash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stash_(software)) is `atlassian-stash`. This is  about neither, it's about Bitbucket.

Answer (score 1):

Once you login into your Bitbucket account and check out the repository, you will see all the tags listed.

Click on the tag link and you will get the URL for the tag.

[image]

Comment: @Pradeep: If i could help you in any way then please accept the answer. Thank you.